# When is pygame.init() needed?

Tags: python, pygame

I am studying pygame and in the vast majority of tutorials it is said that one should run `pygame.init()` before doing anything. I was doing one particular tutorial and typing out the code as one does and noticed that in example after example there is no `pygame.init()` and no other explicit initialisation of any modules.

For instance, the following works (for me, at least) without any issues:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
```

Just wondering how to find out exactly what is initialised when `pygame.init()` is run and what is initialised when `pygame.init()` is not run.

Answer (score 1):

> This will attempt to initialize all the pygame modules for you. **Not
>   all pygame modules need to be initialized**, but this will automatically
>   initialize the ones that do.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html

I don't know what modules must be initialized, but it looks like *display* and *event* aren't in that category. I just recommend you to do it, because maybe some modules can work without being initialized but won't work the same way or they'll miss something important.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of modules by:

```
numpass, numfail = pygame.init()
```

pygame.init() will initialize for example the `joystick`, `font` or `mixer` modules.
The `scrap` module will require a separate init.
And the `midi` module will need a separate init and import.

```
pygame.init()

print(pygame.font.get_init())  # True
print(pygame.joystick.get_init())  # True
print(pygame.scrap.get_init())  # False
print(pygame.midi.get_init())  # AttributeError
```

For midi:

```
import pygame.midi

pygame.midi.init()
print(pygame.midi.get_init())  # True
```

For scrap:

```
pygame.scrap.init()
print(pygame.scrap.get_init())  # True
```