# Pygame calling or calling not the pygame.init()

Tags: pygame

Why is pygame working for me, without having called `pygame.init()` at the start of the code? I ask just out of curiosity, because it works also without `pygame.init()`.

**EDIT-example**

I have the following:

```
import pygame
#pygame.init()

TV=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
runs=1
while runs:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==pygame.QUIT:
            runs=0
```

If i close the screen (using the close button), i test this also with the `pygame.init()` line uncommented and in both cases i get no errors.
I run it also using `pygame.quit()` instaed of `runs=0` line (with once `pygame.init()` line commented and once uncommented), i get in BOTH cases this:

```
    for e in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

which is because the `while` loop still runs one more time after `pygame.quit()` has been called, causing the error, but this is i suppose not type of error we are talking about.

Comment: Without `pygame.init()` it will throw an error if you quit your program using `pygame.quit()`

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is pygame.init() needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827947/when-is-pygame-init-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Some "modules" of pygame need to be initialized, but not all. Pygame.init() inizializes all "modules" but you also can do that for every "module" individually. Here a helpfull link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html